# how can make the same thing on different activities without copying code

Tags: java, android

i am working with android studio and would like to know how to change something in the code and make the app recalculate everything again for example if after a click i change a text (with settext....) the app have to use the new data in the text to make the same thing the only solution that i have for now is to copy code on many activities for each change made. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean strings? You can create string resources so if you change the value of one string it gets updated in every view that uses it without you having to manually rephrase that everywhere. Read more about this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource

Comment: post some code, to  let us better help you.

Answer (score 0):

To reuse the code you can create a new class (e.g. `Utils.java`) in your package and put inside it all methods you'll use in more the one java class.

Alternatively:

You can pass values between activities by adding extra information in the `Intent` used to open the next Activity, through the [putExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("NAME_FOR_EXTRA_DATA", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

to get that value from `NextActivity.class`:

```
String extraData = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME_FOR_EXTRA_DATA");
```

where `NAME_FOR_EXTRA_DATA` is a name chosen by you.

Comment: but i dont really want to past value i wan t reuse the same code without going to aother activity lets take an example if the user click 1 the app show 1

Comment: You're talking about the same activity, but I have a doubt: are you using methods?

Comment: but i dont really want to past value i wan t reuse the same code without going to aother activity lets take an example if the user click a correct  answer to the asked question the app show correct the change the question to a new one so that when the user click again for the answer to the new question so that the app will verify the aswer associated with that particular text(question)

Comment: please be more precise... you are writing confusing

Comment: if i change the text manually the my app verify the answer correctly but if i set a method to change the qestions randomly the app think that it is the last text and still keep the last answer

Comment: i was trying to upload a bit of the code but i can't

Comment: so i will try to explain each part

Comment: i created an array of questions  then a array of answers each question as the same index as the question so that i create a method wich will find the index then with the "if the index are equal when the user click it will show correct if not it will show incorrect

Comment: please use "google translator" for English, then post some code in your question post (you can obfuscate the names of fields/methods/etc)